# How to use a variable declared in sciplet in other part of jsp

Tags: jsp

```
<%
ResourceBundle mybundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MyLabels");
String login=mybundle.getString("Login");
String reset=mybundle.getString("Reset");

%>
<fieldset>
        Login Screen <br> <br>
        <hr>
            <center>
                <table>

                    <form action="/Login" method="post">
                        <tr>
                            <td>User Id</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="userid" id="userid"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Password</td>
                            <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength=3
                                value=""></td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
            </center>
            <br> <br>
            <center>
                <input type="submit" value=login>>
                <button type="reset" value=reset>Reset</button>
        </form>
        </center>
</body>
```

I need to use String login and reset as value for the button.
How to do it? Am I correct in my approach?

Comment: 2 ways:

1 - Add as Session attribute
2 - Add in model map

Comment: use Request attribute .

Comment: Hi, @Shiv keerthi, I would suggest you to go through some beginners tutorials, just google it you will get plenty, try and understand and then code by yourself that will help you improve. Hope this helps.